# switch focus to pane by number id in tmux

Tags: tmux

In tmux, when I press `ctrl + b + q`, it shows a number id for each pane. Normally I navigate between panes with `ctrl + b + arrow`. Is there a similar shortcut to move directly to a pane by its id as shown by `ctrl + b + q`?

Answer (score 8):

You just need to press the number on the pane you want to switch to while the number is still showing up.